# No output in eclipse (Linux GCC)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've compiled a c++ file with Linux GCC compiler via eclipse , and it works fine without any error , but the problem that I face is that I cannot see any output from eclipse .
The code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char reverseMe[] = {"reverseText"};
for(int v = sizeof(reverseMe) ; v >= 0 ; v--){
    cout << reverseMe[v] << flush;
}
return 0;
}
```

In addition , I've launched the same code in online-c++-compiler , and it works fine and it gives me the result ! , but in eclipse , no output at all..
However , if I just replace 'flush' with 'endl' it gives me the result each character per one line (in eclipse),but I want the result to be in only one line.
So where is the problem ?

NOTE: I'm using Ubuntu 14 LTS , 64 bit

Comment: Print out a single new-line at the end of your program (or a single `std::endl`). This may be a failure of Eclipse expecting full-line output (but I'm not sure).

Comment: @Steve , I tried that before , unfortunately doesn't work ..